# Can we to use the single Action Bar for all Activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have `Action bar` and a lot of different `Activity`, its working, but I don't want to add code in every `Activity`. How to add one code in one `Activity` that will work in every `Activity`? I expect to write only one code in one `Activity` for all activities.

My main activity:

```
package ua.in.masterpc.technoguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class IconsMain extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_icons_main);

    ImageButton myImageButton = findViewById(R.id.iconPC);
  myImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(IconsMain.this, PCProblems.class);
          startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
      }
  });
    }

@Override//start menu code
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.bar_menu, menu);
    return true;
    }//end menu code
}
```

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create class named `BaseActivity` which will extend `AppCompatActivity` and put there the code and functionality you want to use in every other `Activity`. Then in every of your activities, you will extend `BaseActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. By doing that you can avoid duplicating your code. Remember that you will have to put `ActionBar` in every activity `.xml` layout file.

Comment: Thank you, Dawid. I will be try.

Answer (score 0):

*create a `baseActivity`* 
add function inside it to initialize the toolbar and customize it as you like

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 protected fun initializeToolbar() {
 val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
   }
}
```

*create `toolbar_main.xml`*

*extends the `baseActivity`* in any activty after including the `toolbar_main.xml` as `<include layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />`

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(){
}
```

and call the function you created in `baseActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a layout say, toolbar_layout, and add the the code for your layout, then include the layout in all your activities: